# What does a Groovy Writable Interface do?

Tags: groovy, interface

Can anyone please explain the purpose of Groovy's `Writable` interface? What does it buy us that returning a `Writer` object does not?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Writable.html):

> Represents an object which is capable of writing itself to a text stream in a more efficient format than just creating a toString() representation of itself. This mechanism is particularly useful for templates and such like.

Or did you want more?